# "var opn = require('opn');" not working when package installed on linux mint

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-packager

I'm trying to carry out some simple steps in an application I've written. I'm trying to open a text file in a specified folder. I'm using Linux mint-19.1-cinnamon-64bit.

The below works when I run the package using 'npm start'. However, when I package the code and install it, the command does not work.

```
logPath ="/home/user/Logs/Scans.txt"
var opn = require('opn');
opn(logPath);
```

It throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:357)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:540)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/electron-tutorial-app/resources/app.asar/node_modules/opn/index.js:76)
    at viewLogs (mainWindow.html:1822)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (mainWindow.html:2279)
errnoException @ internal/errors.js:308
ChildProcess.spawn @ internal/child_process.js:357
spawn @ child_process.js:540
module.exports @ /usr/lib/electron-tutorial-app/resources/app.asar/node_modules/opn/index.js:76
viewLogs @ mainWindow.html:1822
onclick @ mainWindow.html:2279
```

Not sure why such a simple command won't work.

Edit for dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.3",
    "inquirer-select-directory": "^1.2.0",
    "lockfile": "^1.0.4",
    "node-localstorage": "^1.3.1",
    "opn": "^5.4.0",
    "proper-lockfile": "^3.2.0",
    "retry": "^0.12.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.5",
    "electron-installer-dmg": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^12.2.0",
    "electron-winstaller": "^2.7.0"
  }
```

Comment: Does `xdg-open /home/user/Logs/Scans.txt` work in terminal?

Comment: @tbking Yes it works fine and opens Scans.txt in the default text editor.

Comment: Can you post your dependencies? Maybe from `package.json`?

Comment: @Mortz I've added the dependencies above. Maybe "opn" isn't being packaged properly? All the other dependencies work fine. I've tried repackaging multiple times but still get the same error.

Comment: @Physicsman - I don't have access to Node to try this out but https://discuss.atom.io/t/asar-limitations-on-node-api-spawn-a-child/28235 seems to suggest that the problem is `__dirname` - i.e. when you run the process in `nodejs` it finds `xdg-open` in the current directory but there is no `xdg-open` in the electron app directory. You could try creating a shortcut/symlink to `xdg-open` in the directory of your electron app and see it that helps.

Comment: @Mortz Ok thank you I’ll have a look into that